# apache2 won't start on boot because of "no listening sockets available" error

Tags: apache-2.2, ipv6

When booting a debian wheezy server using apache2 version `2.2.22`, the apache autostart fails with the following error:

```
Starting web server: apache2(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address [2a01:aaa:bbb:ccc::2]:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

I already checked if port 80 is already being used by another process using netstat - it is not.

The ipv6 setup is native, not using any tunnels. This is the used `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:aaa:bbb:ccc::2
  netmask 64
  gateway 2a01:aaa:bbb:ccc::1
```

I also tried setting the `S[xx]apache2` number used by rc.d higher then the ones of all the other process, still the same error.

When later starting apache manually using `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` over ssh, everything works fine.

How could I possibly fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're trying to start apache before the network is started. Try starting it at a later time in the boot process.

Comment: I set a ID higher then all the other processes ones in rc.d, still the same error.